AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer Issue (502 Bad Gateway and Health Checks Failing)
I'm new to AWS and created a project where I had my front end deployed using one AWS EB single instance and my backend deployed using a separate EB single instance. I had no issues so I set up a custom domain that I connected to my front end EB env using route 53 (aliasing). I then wanted to use https throughout the project because I was having issues with cookies (I needed to use them and wasn't seeing them despite including them and having my backend set up with cookies). When switching to https I read that I should switch from single instance to load balancer so I did that for my front and backend and registered an SSL cert that I connected to my custom domain (which I aliased to my front end load balancer instead of my single instance). I then manually installed and configured a ssl/tls cert for my backend eb single instance. I set up listeners for port 80 and 443:   with these health check settings for my target groups:  and listener rules that looked like this for the https listener:   and this for the http listener:  and set up my front end server with this to deal with healthchecks:
app.get('/health', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});

with a file in the ebextensions that I uploaded that should forward anything that isn't /health to https: files:
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        location /health {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
      }


Target group for http (have one for https that looks pretty similar):
I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure out how to fix this because I cannot get log output for the load balanced front end via the AWS UI and was ssh-ing into my single instance before but since I've moved from a single instance to load balanced for the front end, I don't know how to get the full logs for the front end. All I see when I try to navigate to my custom domain now is a 502 Bad Gateway but nothing else that is helpful in the network tab or console tab of dev tools. If anyone has any advice for dealing with this error I get when requesting logs in the AWS UI (but don't see anything useful in dev tools):  or how to fix the health checks issue I am seeing that would be so appreciated!!! If you see a different mistake I am making and can help me out or direct me to a resource that could help with either issue, that would also be really appreciated. Banging my head against my laptop at this point because everything I've read hasn't helped.
I've tried to get log output to debug with no success. I also tried setting up new listener rules, updating registered targets in the target groups to include more ports in case I was mistaken in the port, and have tried changing the alias for the custom domain.

ssh into the instance and you can check the logs under /var/logs

also check if /var/app has "current" folder.  If it is not it's a deployment issue

@andylee I can't do that though because I am using a load balancer now, so I can't ssh in like I could before.

you can ssh with or without load balancer.  If you can't there must be something wrong with you configuration.
